# what data structure to use in my case?

Tags: java, data-structures

A `FileManager` Class has a static filed to hold a file collection, this collection may contains files or folders or both , a folder may contains files or folders or both, the `FileManager` Class contains public method for client code to call such as `addFile`, `addFolder`, `deleteFile`, `deleteFolder`, these method operate on the collection. 
My question is:
What java data structure is best for this case ?
How to create model class for File and Folder ?

some example will be good.

best regars.

// added @ 2011/05/27
thank everybody !
acutaly I am trying to buidl a eclipse-rcp application to manage some jdbc connection profile.
here is my code:

```
package com.amarsoft.sysconfig.plugin.model;

/**
 * @author ggfan@amarsoft
 *
 */
public class TreeNode {

    /**
     * unique key
     */
    private String key;

    /**
     * used as label in a JFace TreeViewer, 
     */
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }


}

public class LeafNode extends TreeNode {

    private FolderNode parent;

    public void setParent(FolderNode parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public TreeNode getParent() {
        return parent;
    }
}
```

package com.amarsoft.sysconfig.plugin.model;

import java.util.List;

```
public class FolderNode extends TreeNode {

    private List<TreeNode> children;

    public void setChildren(List<TreeNode> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }

    public List<TreeNode> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }
}




package com.amarsoft.sysconfig.plugin.model;

import org.dom4j.Element;
import org.dom4j.tree.DefaultElement;

/**
 * 连接配置模型类
 * @author ggfan@amarsoft
 *
 */
public class ConnectionProfile extends LeafNode{

    /**
     * url
     */
    private String url;

    /**
     * JDBC driver id
     */
    private int driver;

    /**
     * user name for logon
     */
    private String user;

    /**
     * password for logon
     */
    private String pswd;

    /**
     * default constructor
     */
    public ConnectionProfile() {

    }

    /**
     * construct a instance using a XML element
     * @param xmlElement the XML element
     */
    public ConnectionProfile(Element xmlElement){
        this.setName(xmlElement.attributeValue("name"));
        this.setUrl(xmlElement.element("url").getTextTrim());
        this.setUser(xmlElement.element("user").getTextTrim());
        this.setPswd(xmlElement.element("password").getTextTrim());
    }

    /**
     * serialize as XML
     * @return
     */
    public Element asXML(){
        Element e = new DefaultElement("profile");
        e.addAttribute("name", this.getName());
        e.addElement("url", escapeNull(this.getUrl()));
        e.addElement("user", escapeNull(this.getUser()));
        e.addElement("password", escapeNull(this.getPswd()));
        return e;
    }

    private String escapeNull(String s) {
        return s == null ? "" : s;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getPswd() {
        return pswd;
    }

    public void setPswd(String pswd) {
        this.pswd = pswd;
    }

    public void setDriver(int driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public int getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

}
```

public class ConnectionProfileManager {

```
private static List<TreeNode> profiles = new ArrayList<TreeNode>();

public static void loadProfiles() throws DocumentException{
    Element profiles = XMLUtil.readRoot(ConnectionProfileManager.class.getResourceAsStream("samples_profile.xml"));
    //Element profiles = XMLUtil.readRoot(new File(ApplicationFiles.CONNNECTION_PROFILES));
    if(profiles != null){
        for(Element profile : profiles.elements()){
            loadNode(profile, ConnectionProfileManager.profiles);
        }
    }
}


private static void loadNode(Element node, List<TreeNode> parent){
    if(node.getName().equals(XMLConstants.CP_TAG_PROFILE)){
        ConnectionProfile profile = new ConnectionProfile(node);
        parent.add(profile);
    }else if(node.getName().equals(XMLConstants.CP_TAG_FOLDER)){
        FolderNode folder = new FolderNode();
        folder.setChildren(new ArrayList<TreeNode>());
        folder.setName(node.attributeValue(XMLConstants.CP_ATTR_NAME));
        for(Element child : node.elements()){
            loadNode(child, folder.getChildren());
        }
        parent.add(folder);
    }
}

public static void saveProfiles(){
    Element root = new DefaultElement(XMLConstants.CP_TAG_PROFILES);
    for(TreeNode node : ConnectionProfileManager.profiles){
        saveNode(node, root);
    }

    XMLUtil.save(root, new File("c:\\1.xml"));
}

private static void saveNode(TreeNode node, Element root) {
    if(node instanceof ConnectionProfile){
        ConnectionProfile p = (ConnectionProfile)node;
        root.add(p.asXML());
    }else if(node instanceof FolderNode){
        FolderNode folder = (FolderNode)node;
        Element e = new DefaultElement(XMLConstants.CP_TAG_FOLDER);
        e.addAttribute(XMLConstants.CP_ATTR_NAME, node.getName());
        for(TreeNode child : folder.getChildren()){
            saveNode(child, e);
        }
        root.add(e);
    }
}


public static void addProfile(ConnectionProfile profile){
    profiles.add(profile);
}

public static void addProfile(TreeNode parentNode, ConnectionProfile profile){

}

public static List<TreeNode> getProfiles() {
    return profiles;
}
```

}

**with these class I get my tree works, but I found It's hard to support add operation.**

Comment: This is a homework or what ? btw. what is that both

Comment: I think to keep file and folders in one collection is good thing, because you can process  files and folders using recursion mechanism by iterating over collection, e. g. if a folder contains files you can simply call the same function to process it.

Comment: Isn't your `FileManager` class a *kind of* directory that maps names to files (and other directories)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've kinda of dictacted the answer already in the question..

The `File` class is (according to the [JavaDocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html)) an:

> abstract representation of file and directory pathnames.

So from what you've described:

```
 // A file manager class
 class FileManager {

     // has a static field to hold a file collection 
     static Collection<File> fileCollection;

     // contains public methods such as
     public addFile(File f) { }
     public deleteFile(File f) { }
     public addFolder(File f) { }
     public deleteFolder(File f { }
 }
```

If you have to look at implementing your own version of the `File` class, then the JavaDocs for that should be a good start to understanding this.

AS to what collection is best for the file collection, I think a `Set` makes most sense.  There's no point having more than one file (e.g. a List and two entries of the same file would be meaningless), and testing membership of a set is a very quick operation.  For example, in `addFile` you might check it exists before trying to add, and similarly for `delete` you'd want to make sure that it exists before you delete it.

A couple of points about the design you've mentioned.

1. Static fields like this as nasty.  They make it difficult to test and are a pain for multi-threading.  Could you make it an instance variable?
2. Given that `File` is an abstract representation of a path name, why'd you need the method `addFile` and `addFolder`, they are going to have the same implementation?

Answer (score 2):

A [Collection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) of [File](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html)s?

Most collections support add and delete, so there is no need for a special data structure. Java File can be a file and a directory. Simply call [isDirectory](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory%28%29) to find out if it is a directory or a file.

Unless you have more requirements, I think this would make up a pretty easy to use FileManager:

```
List<File> fileManager = new ArrayList<File>();
```